# pushwoosh error unrecognized selector sent to instance Cordova 1.7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, apple-push-notifications, server-push

I am trying out pushwoosh and tried unregistering an iOS device on the remote api and this error came up:

```
-[__NSDictionaryI cdvjk_JSONString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    [__NSDictionaryI cdvjk_JSONString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
*** First throw call stack:
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
 Sending request: {"request":{"hwid":"my_hwid", "application":"my_app_id"}}
To urL https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/pushStat
(lldb)
```

I then realized that the unregister method is implemented only for androids and not iOS devices so that request was not being used by the pushwoosh plugins in the plugins folder.

I removed the code from my index.js and pushnotifications.js files but still the error came up every time I tried to launch the app after accepting a push notification.

I then removed this code from the remote api:

```
 new JObject(
             new JProperty("custom", "json data"))),
             new JProperty("link", "http://pushwoosh.com/")
```

with the hope that the seemingly custom data wil not be sent to pushwoosh.

Still the error appears. I know that the problem is that an unhanded request is being made every time but the problem is that the code does not exist.

Could I have possibly edited some method signatures and these signatures are being used each and every time I try to accept a push notification?

Or is it that Xcode performs auto-complete?

I would need someone who is familiar with pushwoosh (and Xcode) to help me out here. What would be the workaround without having to upgrade to Cordova 2.1.0 or later since (This error comes from the plugin itself, Phonegap guys have changed the way "JSONString" objective-c function gets called by adding prefix "cdvjk_" breaking the compatibility of the plugins with any < 2.1 Phonegap versions.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read this thread. Unfortunately, this is kinda fault of PhoneGap guys, who made it impossible to support both Cordova 2.1 and earlier versions:

https://github.com/shaders/phonegap-cordova-push-notifications/issues/12

You can contact Pushwoosh team asking if they still can help you with the older versions.

Comment: I did contact them, and as I specified in the question (indirectly) they recommended upgrading, so I was wondering if there is not any other way around this besides upgrading which is unfortunately what I foresee myself doing.

Comment: You can manually change the plugin code removing "cdvjk_" prefixes and it would work fine with < 2.1 Cordova.